# 404 error after incorporationg spring security to my project

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am learning how to filter requests with springs.Using spring security for it. After writing the spring-security.xml file in my project, I am getting a 404 error. Please help.

spring-security.xml:

```
  <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
      xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" /> -->
      <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_MODERATOR" />  

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/login" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="src/main/java/service/UserServiceDetailsImpl" >
        <password-encoder hash="{sha}" />    
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

 </beans:beans>
```

web.xml file:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

UserServiceDetailsImpl class :

```
     package service;



import model.Login;



@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class UserServiceDetailsImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private MusicPlayerServiceImpl2 service;    

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

      Login domainLogin = service.loadUserByUsername(userName);

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(
                domainLogin.getUserName(),
                domainLogin.getPassword(), 
                enabled, 
                accountNonExpired, 
                credentialsNonExpired, 
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(domainLogin.getRole().getId())
        );
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (role.intValue() == 1) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
        } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        }
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role));
        }
        return authorities;
      }

    }
```

Login page :

```
      <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css.map">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
<script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="preview__header">
        <div class="preview__envato-logo">
            <h4>MusicPlayer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="login_main_cont">
        <div class="login_cont group login">
                <div class="login_form modal-signup">
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <form method="post" name="login" action="login"
                        class="formClass">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control focusedInput"
                                id="username" placeholder="username" name="username" required />
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="spacer10"></div>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control focusedInput"
                                id="loginPassword" placeholder="password" name="password"
                                required />
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="spacer10"></div>
                        <fieldset class="login_submit">
                            <button type="submit" class="buton">SIGN IN</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <div class="spacer10"></div>
                    <a class="link-sign" href="register" align="center" >Don't have
                        an account?&nbsp;Sign up!</a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="container" align="center">
<h4><strong>MusicPlayer</strong></h4>
<form role="form" method="post" name="login" action="loginServlet" class="form-inline" >
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control focusedInput" id="username" placeholder="username" name="username"/>
</div><br><div class="spacer10"></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control focusedInput" id="loginPassword" placeholder="password" name="password" />
</div><br><div class="spacer10"></div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login" value="Login" />
</form><div class="spacer10"></div>

 <a href="register" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Register
   </a> -->
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="w-container center">
        <div class="modal-signup">
            <div class="signup-form">
                <form method="post" name="login" action="loginServlet"
                    class="form-inline">
                    <input type="text" class="w-input singup-field" id="username"
                        placeholder="username" name="username" required /> <input
                        type="password" class="w-input singup-field" id="password"
                        placeholder="password" name="password" required /> <input
                        class="w-button notify-btn sign-btn" type="submit"
                        value="sign in!" data-wait="Please wait..." id="login">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

I don't where I am going wrong.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the controller,index.jsp and default login page.So that one person can analyze and help you to resolve the issue.I hope you will upload the details soon.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code i found one mistake not related to your problem but still its need to be corrected for using the spring security for login  you should use in login form

```
<form  name="login" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST" >

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" name='j_username'>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name='j_password'>

</form>
```